# What is a "Delta HDF Faucet?"

Tags: faucet, delta

Purchased and installed a **Delta T17T238** shower trim set in 2011.

Perusing the included "Installation Instructions" manual, I encountered the following warranty verbiage:

[image: HDF]

Well, Goggle was not my friend, and Delta's Customer Service email interface seems to be down at the moment.

Any insight as to what "HDF" stands for?

Comment: Looks like they might be commercial quality, hence the 5 year limited warrant

Comment: @LimoDRIVER I was able to get thru to Delta Customer Service. Indeed, "HDF" stands for "Heavy Duty Faucet." You pretty much supplied the correct solution. If you write this up as an answer, I'll select it as the correct one..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they might be commercial quality, hence the 5 year limited warranty.   More specifically, according to Delta Customer Service, **HDF** stands for "Heavy Duty Faucet."